# How to query items from DynamoDB that only have unique attribute values?

Tags: java, database, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table that has an attribute with many repeating values.  I would like to query so that I can get all the unique values from this attribute.  Right now, in order to make querying easier, I have made an extra attribute called "uniquenessFlag" and set it to 1 for the first occurring unique attribute.  I set a filterexpression: "attribute_exists(uniquenessFlag)" so that the only items that are returned are the items with unique attribute value.  I was wondering if there was an easier way of doing this?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Have you tried using the secondary index?